# Ubuntu 10.04 not detecting multiple monitors

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, ubuntu-10.04

I have 2 graphics cards, the output from the lspci:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RV770 [Radeon HD 4850]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RV710 [Radeon HD 4350]
```

I have one monitor connected to the 4850 and 2 connected to the 4350. However when I go into System > Preferences > Monitors the only monitor shown is the one connected to the 4850.

Is there something I need to enable for it to be able to use the other card? How do I get this to work.

Thanks.

As per request:

```
X.Org X Server 1.7.6
Release Date: 2010-03-17
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.24-25-server i686 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux jeff-desktop 2.6.32-22-generic-pae #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 28 14:57:29 UTC 2010 i686
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-22-generic-pae root=UUID=852e1013-4ed6-40fd-a462-c29087888383 ro quiet splash
Build Date: 23 April 2010  05:11:50PM
xorg-server 2:1.7.6-2ubuntu7 (Bryce Harrington <bryce@ubuntu.com>) 
Current version of pixman: 0.16.4
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue May 11 08:24:52 2010
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using config directory: "/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
(**) |-->Screen "Default Screen" (0)
(**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
(==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen".
    Using the first device section listed.
(**) |   |-->Device "Default Device"
(==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
(==) Automatically adding devices
(==) Automatically enabling devices
(WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
    Entry deleted from font path.
(==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType,
    built-ins
(==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
(II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
(II) Loader magic: 0x81f0e80
(II) Module ABI versions:
    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
    X.Org Video Driver: 6.0
    X.Org XInput driver : 7.0
    X.Org Server Extension : 2.0
(++) using VT number 7

(--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 1002:9442:174b:e104 ATI Technologies Inc RV770 [Radeon HD 4850] rev 0, Mem @ 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xfe7e0000/65536, I/O @ 0x0000a000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
(--) PCI: (0:2:0:0) 1002:954f:1462:1618 ATI Technologies Inc RV710 [Radeon HD 4350] rev 0, Mem @ 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xfe8e0000/65536, I/O @ 0x0000b000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
(WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
(II) "extmod" will be loaded by default.
(II) "dbe" will be loaded by default.
(II) "glx" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
(II) "record" will be loaded by default.
(II) "dri" will be loaded by default.
(II) "dri2" will be loaded by default.
(II) LoadModule: "glx"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules/modules/extensions/libglx.so
(II) Module glx: vendor="FireGL - ATI Technologies Inc."
    compiled for 7.5.0, module version = 1.0.0
(II) Loading extension GLX
(II) LoadModule: "extmod"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
(II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.7.6, module version = 1.0.0
    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 2.0
(II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
(II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
(II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
(II) Loading extension DPMS
(II) Loading extension XVideo
(II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
(II) Loading extension X-Resource
(II) LoadModule: "dbe"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
(II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.7.6, module version = 1.0.0
    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 2.0
(II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
(II) LoadModule: "record"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
(II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.7.6, module version = 1.13.0
    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 2.0
(II) Loading extension RECORD
(II) LoadModule: "dri"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
(II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.7.6, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 2.0
(II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
(II) LoadModule: "dri2"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
(II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.7.6, module version = 1.1.0
    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 2.0
(II) Loading extension DRI2
(II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
(II) Module fglrx: vendor="FireGL - ATI Technologies Inc."
    compiled for 1.7.1, module version = 8.72.11
    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
(II) Loading sub module "fglrxdrm"
(II) LoadModule: "fglrxdrm"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so
(II) Module fglrxdrm: vendor="FireGL - ATI Technologies Inc."
    compiled for 1.7.1, module version = 8.72.11
(II) ATI Proprietary Linux Driver Version Identifier:8.72.11
(II) ATI Proprietary Linux Driver Release Identifier: 8.723.1                              
(II) ATI Proprietary Linux Driver Build Date: Apr  8 2010 21:40:29
(II) Primary Device is: PCI 01@00:00:0
(WW) Falling back to old probe method for fglrx
(II) Loading PCS database from /etc/ati/amdpcsdb
(--) Assigning device section with no busID to primary device
(WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@2:0:0) found
(--) Chipset Supported AMD Graphics Processor (0x9442) found
(WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@1:0:1) found
(WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@2:0:1) found
(**) ChipID override: 0x954F
(**) Chipset Supported AMD Graphics Processor (0x954F) found
(II) AMD Video driver is running on a device belonging to a group targeted for this release
(II) AMD Video driver is signed
(II) fglrx(0): pEnt->device->identifier=0x9428aa0
(II) pEnt->device->identifier=(nil)
(II) fglrx(0): === [atiddxPreInit] === begin
(II) Loading sub module "vgahw"
(II) LoadModule: "vgahw"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvgahw.so
(II) Module vgahw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.7.6, module version = 0.1.0
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 6.0
(II) fglrx(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
(**) fglrx(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
(II) fglrx(0): Pixel depth = 24 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
(==) fglrx(0): Default visual is TrueColor
(==) fglrx(0): RGB weight 888
(II) fglrx(0): Using 8 bits per RGB 
(==) fglrx(0): Buffer Tiling is ON
(II) Loading sub module "fglrxdrm"
(II) LoadModule: "fglrxdrm"
(II) Reloading /usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 251
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 251
ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:1:0:0
ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
ukiOpenDevice: open result is 10, (OK)
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 10
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:2:0:0
ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card1
ukiOpenDevice: open result is 10, (OK)
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 10
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:1:0:0
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 251
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 251
ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:2:0:0
ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
ukiOpenDevice: open result is 11, (OK)
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 11
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:2:0:0
(--) fglrx(0): Chipset: "ATI Radeon HD 4800 Series" (Chipset = 0x9442)
(--) fglrx(0): (PciSubVendor = 0x174b, PciSubDevice = 0xe104)
(==) fglrx(0): board vendor info: third party graphics adapter - NOT original ATI
(--) fglrx(0): Linear framebuffer (phys) at 0xc0000000
(--) fglrx(0): MMIO registers at 0xfe7e0000
(--) fglrx(0): I/O port at 0x0000a000
(==) fglrx(0): ROM-BIOS at 0x000c0000
(II) fglrx(0): AC Adapter is used
(II) fglrx(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
(II) Loading sub module "vbe"
(II) LoadModule: "vbe"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
(II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.7.6, module version = 1.1.0
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 6.0
(II) fglrx(0): VESA BIOS detected
(II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
(II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 16384 kB
(II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE OEM: ATI ATOMBIOS
(II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 11.13
(II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: (C) 1988-2005, ATI Technologies Inc. 
(II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: RV770
(II) fglrx(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: 01.00
(II) fglrx(0): ATI Video BIOS revision 9 or later detected
(--) fglrx(0): Video RAM: 524288 kByte, Type: GDDR3
(II) fglrx(0): PCIE card detected
(--) fglrx(0): Using per-process page tables (PPPT) as GART.
(WW) fglrx(0): board is an unknown third party board, chipset is supported
(--) fglrx(0): Chipset: "ATI Radeon HD 4300/4500 Series" (Chipset = 0x954f)
(--) fglrx(0): (PciSubVendor = 0x1462, PciSubDevice = 0x1618)
(==) fglrx(0): board vendor info: third party graphics adapter - NOT original ATI
(--) fglrx(0): Linear framebuffer (phys) at 0xd0000000
(--) fglrx(0): MMIO registers at 0xfe8e0000
(--) fglrx(0): I/O port at 0x0000b000
(==) fglrx(0): ROM-BIOS at 0x000c0000
(II) fglrx(0): AC Adapter is used
(II) fglrx(0): Invalid ATI BIOS from int10, the adapter is not VGA-enabled
(II) fglrx(0): ATI Video BIOS revision 9 or later detected
(--) fglrx(0): Video RAM: 524288 kByte, Type: DDR2
(II) fglrx(0): PCIE card detected
(--) fglrx(0): Using per-process page tables (PPPT) as GART.
(WW) fglrx(0): board is an unknown third party board, chipset is supported
(II) fglrx(0): Using adapter: 1:0.0.
(II) fglrx(0): [FB] MC range(MCFBBase = 0xf00000000, MCFBSize = 0x20000000)
(II) fglrx(0): Interrupt handler installed at IRQ 31.
(II) fglrx(0): Using adapter: 2:0.0.
(II) fglrx(0): [FB] MC range(MCFBBase = 0xf00000000, MCFBSize = 0x20000000)
(II) fglrx(0): RandR 1.2 support is enabled!
(II) fglrx(0): RandR 1.2 rotation support is enabled!
(==) fglrx(0): Center Mode is disabled 
(II) Loading sub module "fb"
(II) LoadModule: "fb"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
(II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.7.6, module version = 1.0.0
    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
(II) Loading sub module "ddc"
(II) LoadModule: "ddc"
(II) Module "ddc" already built-in
(II) fglrx(0): Finished Initialize PPLIB!
(II) Loading sub module "ddc"
(II) LoadModule: "ddc"
(II) Module "ddc" already built-in
(II) fglrx(0): Connected Display0: DFP on external TMDS [tmds2]
(II) fglrx(0): Display0 EDID data ---------------------------
(II) fglrx(0): Manufacturer: DEL  Model: a038  Serial#: 810829397
(II) fglrx(0): Year: 2008  Week: 51
(II) fglrx(0): EDID Version: 1.3
(II) fglrx(0): Digital Display Input
(II) fglrx(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 53  vert.: 30
(II) fglrx(0): Gamma: 2.20
(II) fglrx(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off
(II) fglrx(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
(II) fglrx(0): Default color space is primary color space
(II) fglrx(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
(II) fglrx(0): redX: 0.640 redY: 0.330   greenX: 0.300 greenY: 0.600
(II) fglrx(0): blueX: 0.150 blueY: 0.060   whiteX: 0.312 whiteY: 0.329
(II) fglrx(0): Supported established timings:
(II) fglrx(0): 720x400@70Hz
(II) fglrx(0): 640x480@60Hz
(II) fglrx(0): 640x480@75Hz
(II) fglrx(0): 800x600@60Hz
(II) fglrx(0): 800x600@75Hz
(II) fglrx(0): 1024x768@60Hz
(II) fglrx(0): 1024x768@75Hz
(II) fglrx(0): 1280x1024@75Hz
(II) fglrx(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
(II) fglrx(0): Supported standard timings:
(II) fglrx(0): #0: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
(II) fglrx(0): #1: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
(II) fglrx(0): #2: hsize: 1920  vsize 1080  refresh: 60  vid: 49361
(II) fglrx(0): Supported detailed timing:
(II) fglrx(0): clock: 148.5 MHz   Image Size:  531 x 298 mm
(II) fglrx(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 2008  h_sync_end 2052 h_blank_end 2200 h_border: 0
(II) fglrx(0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1084  v_sync_end 1089 v_blanking: 1125 v_border: 0
(II) fglrx(0): Serial No: Y183D8CF0TFU
(II) fglrx(0): Monitor name: DELL S2409W
(II) fglrx(0): Ranges: V min: 50 V max: 76 Hz, H min: 30 H max: 83 kHz, PixClock max 170 MHz
(II) fglrx(0): EDID (in hex):
(II) fglrx(0):  00ffffffffffff0010ac38a055465430
(II) fglrx(0):  3312010380351e78eeee91a3544c9926
(II) fglrx(0):  0f5054a54b00714f8180d1c001010101
(II) fglrx(0):  010101010101023a801871382d40582c
(II) fglrx(0):  4500132a2100001e000000ff00593138
(II) fglrx(0):  3344384346305446550a000000fc0044
(II) fglrx(0):  454c4c205332343039570a20000000fd
(II) fglrx(0):  00324c1e5311000a2020202020200059
(II) fglrx(0): End of Display0 EDID data --------------------
(II) fglrx(0): Output DFP2 has no monitor section
(II) fglrx(0): Output DFP_EXTTMDS has no monitor section
(II) fglrx(0): Output CRT1 has no monitor section
(II) fglrx(0): Output CRT2 has no monitor section
(II) fglrx(0): Output DFP2 disconnected
(II) fglrx(0): Output DFP_EXTTMDS connected
(II) fglrx(0): Output CRT1 disconnected
(II) fglrx(0): Output CRT2 disconnected
(II) fglrx(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
(II) fglrx(0): Output DFP_EXTTMDS using initial mode 1920x1080
(II) fglrx(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
(II) fglrx(0): Adapter ATI Radeon HD 4800 Series has 2 configurable heads and 1 displays connected.
(==) fglrx(0): QBS disabled
(==) fglrx(0):  PseudoColor visuals disabled
(II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
(II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
(II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
(==) fglrx(0): NoAccel = NO
(==) fglrx(0): NoDRI = NO
(==) fglrx(0): Capabilities: 0x00000000
(==) fglrx(0): CapabilitiesEx: 0x00000000
(==) fglrx(0): OpenGL ClientDriverName: "fglrx_dri.so"
(==) fglrx(0): UseFastTLS=0
(==) fglrx(0): BlockSignalsOnLock=1
(--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
(II) Loading extension ATIFGLRXDRI
(II) fglrx(0): doing swlDriScreenInit
(II) fglrx(0): swlDriScreenInit for fglrx driver
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 251
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 251
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 251
ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:1:0:0
ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
ukiOpenDevice: open result is 17, (OK)
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 17
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:2:0:0
ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card1
ukiOpenDevice: open result is 17, (OK)
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 17
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:1:0:0
(II) fglrx(0): [uki] DRM interface version 1.0
(II) fglrx(0): [uki] created "fglrx" driver at busid "PCI:1:0:0"
(II) fglrx(0): [uki] added 8192 byte SAREA at 0x2000
(II) fglrx(0): [uki] mapped SAREA 0x2000 to 0xb6996000
(II) fglrx(0): [uki] framebuffer handle = 0x3000
(II) fglrx(0): [uki] added 1 reserved context for kernel
(II) fglrx(0): swlDriScreenInit done
(II) fglrx(0): Kernel Module Version Information:
(II) fglrx(0):     Name: fglrx
(II) fglrx(0):     Version: 8.72.11
(II) fglrx(0):     Date: Apr  8 2010
(II) fglrx(0):     Desc: ATI FireGL DRM kernel module
(II) fglrx(0): Kernel Module version matches driver.
(II) fglrx(0): Kernel Module Build Time Information:
(II) fglrx(0):     Build-Kernel UTS_RELEASE:        2.6.32-22-generic-pae
(II) fglrx(0):     Build-Kernel MODVERSIONS:        yes
(II) fglrx(0):     Build-Kernel __SMP__:            yes
(II) fglrx(0):     Build-Kernel PAGE_SIZE:          0x1000
(II) fglrx(0): [uki] register handle = 0x00004000
(II) fglrx(0): DRI initialization successfull!
(II) fglrx(0): FBADPhys: 0xf00000000 FBMappedSize: 0x01068000
(II) fglrx(0): FBMM initialized for area (0,0)-(1920,2240)
(II) fglrx(0): FBMM auto alloc for area (0,0)-(1920,1920) (front color buffer - assumption)
(II) fglrx(0): Largest offscreen area available: 1920 x 320
(==) fglrx(0): Backing store disabled
(II) Loading extension FGLRXEXTENSION
(==) fglrx(0): DPMS enabled
(II) fglrx(0): Initialized in-driver Xinerama extension
(**) fglrx(0): Textured Video is enabled.
(II) LoadModule: "glesx"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules/modules/glesx.so
(II) Module glesx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.7.1, module version = 1.0.0
(II) Loading extension GLESX
(II) Loading sub module "xaa"
(II) LoadModule: "xaa"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libxaa.so
(II) Module xaa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.7.6, module version = 1.2.1
    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 6.0
(II) fglrx(0): GLESX enableFlags = 94
(II) fglrx(0): Using XFree86 Acceleration Architecture (XAA)
    Screen to screen bit blits
    Solid filled rectangles
    Solid Horizontal and Vertical Lines
    Driver provided ScreenToScreenBitBlt replacement
    Driver provided FillSolidRects replacement
(II) fglrx(0): GLESX is enabled
(II) LoadModule: "amdxmm"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules/modules/amdxmm.so
(II) Module amdxmm: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.7.1, module version = 1.0.0
(II) Loading extension AMDXVOPL
(II) fglrx(0): UVD2 feature is available
(II) fglrx(0): Enable composite support successfully
(II) fglrx(0): X context handle = 0x1
(II) fglrx(0): [DRI] installation complete
(==) fglrx(0): Silken mouse enabled
(==) fglrx(0): Using HW cursor of display infrastructure!
(II) fglrx(0): Disabling in-server RandR and enabling in-driver RandR 1.2.
(--) RandR disabled
(II) Found 2 VGA devices: arbiter wrapping enabled
(II) Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
(II) Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
(II) Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
(II) Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
(II) Initializing built-in extension XTEST
(II) Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
(II) Initializing built-in extension SYNC
(II) Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
(II) Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
(II) Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
(II) Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
(II) Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
(II) Initializing built-in extension RENDER
(II) Initializing built-in extension RANDR
(II) Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
(II) Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 251
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 251
ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:1:0:0
ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
ukiOpenDevice: open result is 18, (OK)
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 18
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:2:0:0
ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card1
ukiOpenDevice: open result is 18, (OK)
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 18
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:1:0:0
(II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized /usr/lib/dri/fglrx_dri.so
(II) GLX: Initialized DRI GL provider for screen 0
(II) fglrx(0): Enable the clock gating!
(II) fglrx(0): Setting screen physical size to 507 x 285
(II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
(II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
(**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
(II) LoadModule: "evdev"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
(II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
    compiled for 1.7.6, module version = 2.3.2
    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 7.0
(**) Power Button: always reports core events
(**) Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
(II) Power Button: Found keys
(II) Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
(II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD)
(**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
(**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
(**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
(II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
(**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
(**) Power Button: always reports core events
(**) Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
(II) Power Button: Found keys
(II) Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
(II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD)
(**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
(**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
(**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
(II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse (/dev/input/event3)
(**) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
(**) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: always reports core events
(**) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
(II) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Found 12 mouse buttons
(II) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
(II) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Found relative axes
(II) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
(II) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Configuring as mouse
(**) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
(**) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
(II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse" (type: MOUSE)
(II) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
(II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse (/dev/input/mouse1)
(II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)
(II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Multimedia Keyboard (/dev/input/event4)
(**) Logitech USB Multimedia Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
(**) Logitech USB Multimedia Keyboard: always reports core events
(**) Logitech USB Multimedia Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
(II) Logitech USB Multimedia Keyboard: Found keys
(II) Logitech USB Multimedia Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
(II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Multimedia Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD)
(**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
(**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
(**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
(II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Multimedia Keyboard (/dev/input/event5)
(**) Logitech USB Multimedia Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
(**) Logitech USB Multimedia Keyboard: always reports core events
(**) Logitech USB Multimedia Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event5"
(II) Logitech USB Multimedia Keyboard: Found keys
(II) Logitech USB Multimedia Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
(II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Multimedia Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD)
(**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
(**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
(**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
(II) config/udev: Adding input device KEYBOARD (/dev/input/event6)
(**) KEYBOARD: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
(**) KEYBOARD: always reports core events
(**) KEYBOARD: Device: "/dev/input/event6"
(II) KEYBOARD: Found keys
(II) KEYBOARD: Configuring as keyboard
(II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "KEYBOARD" (type: KEYBOARD)
(**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
(**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
(**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
(II) config/udev: Adding input device KEYBOARD (/dev/input/event7)
(**) KEYBOARD: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
(**) KEYBOARD: always reports core events
(**) KEYBOARD: Device: "/dev/input/event7"
(II) KEYBOARD: Found 14 mouse buttons
(II) KEYBOARD: Found scroll wheel(s)
(II) KEYBOARD: Found relative axes
(II) KEYBOARD: Found keys
(II) KEYBOARD: Configuring as mouse
(II) KEYBOARD: Configuring as keyboard
(**) KEYBOARD: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
(**) KEYBOARD: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
(II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "KEYBOARD" (type: KEYBOARD)
(**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
(**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
(**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
(EE) KEYBOARD: failed to initialize for relative axes.
(II) config/udev: Adding input device KEYBOARD (/dev/input/mouse2)
(II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)
(II) config/udev: Adding input device Macintosh mouse button emulation (/dev/input/event2)
(**) Macintosh mouse button emulation: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
(**) Macintosh mouse button emulation: always reports core events
(**) Macintosh mouse button emulation: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
(II) Macintosh mouse button emulation: Found 3 mouse buttons
(II) Macintosh mouse button emulation: Found relative axes
(II) Macintosh mouse button emulation: Found x and y relative axes
(II) Macintosh mouse button emulation: Configuring as mouse
(**) Macintosh mouse button emulation: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
(**) Macintosh mouse button emulation: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
(II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Macintosh mouse button emulation" (type: MOUSE)
(II) Macintosh mouse button emulation: initialized for relative axes.
(II) config/udev: Adding input device Macintosh mouse button emulation (/dev/input/mouse0)
(II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)
(II) fglrx(0): Restoring Recent Mode via PCS is not supported in RANDR 1.2 capable environments
```

Comment: Post a link to your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: Here is the file!

Answer (score 3):

That won't work.  See, the powers that be at Xorg have decided that removing the ability of people with multiple boards to configure them is preferable to people with laptops needing to learn how to do things themselves.

XRandR 1.2 does NOT support multiple boards (GPU Object Support).  It was slated for release with 1.3, but is now moved out to 2.0.  What really angers me is, no one notified me.  I've been running multiple boards since Slackware 7, and now, I can't so long as those boards have drivers which are XRandR aware.

In short, you either have to revert to an older version of X, or revert to an older driver.  Either way, the guys at X have their heads up their own butts.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to configure that in the **ATI Catalyst Control Center** application.  I'm not sure where, exactly you'd find that under Gnome.  In KDE, it's in Applications -> Settings for me.  That's what I had to do in Kubuntu 10.04 to get my two monitors recognized.

If you have the proprietary drivers installed, that should be there, too.  It updated xorg.conf for me.  Alternatively, you'll need to set that up manually.  Here's my xorg.conf, for reference:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "amdcccle Layout"
        Screen      0  "amdcccle-Screen[1]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
        Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
        Option      "Xinerama" "off"
EndSection


Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "0-LVDS"
        Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
        Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
        Option      "DPMS" "true"
        Option      "PreferredMode" "1600x900"
        Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
        Option      "Position" "1920 0"
        Option      "Rotate" "normal"
        Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "0-CRT1"
        Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
        Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
        Option      "DPMS" "true"
        Option      "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
        Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
        Option      "Position" "0 0"
        Option      "Rotate" "normal"
        Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Default Device"
        Driver      "fglrx"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "amdcccle-Device[1]-0"
        Driver      "fglrx"
        Option      "Monitor-LVDS" "0-LVDS"
        Option      "Monitor-CRT1" "0-CRT1"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Default Screen"
        DefaultDepth     24
EndSection
```

Comment: For Gnome it should be `System -> Administration`.

Answer (score 1):

First backup your `xorg.conf` by copying it to your home director 
(`cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /home/whatever`)

Then issue the following command from a terminal

```
sudo aticonfig --initial=dual-head --adapter=all
```

this will initiate all your cards by creating a new `xorg.conf` file.

Reboot your machine. (or restart X).

When it comes backup all the monitors will be working. Now launch the ATI catalyst control center and work around with the positions of the monitor e.t.c

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to edit your xorg.conf file. 
In the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file there is a section called "device".
You need to have 1 device section per each video card in your system.

inside the "device" section you give a unique name to each video card so X knows which one you are talking about, then some other options, such as where on the PCI bus the device is located.

For example, by reading the xorg.conf device section, it knows video card 1 is at location "PCI:1:0:0" and the second card (in it's own device section) is located at "PCI:2:0:0".  The 0 and 1 are from your output of lspci in your question.  It doesn't matter in this case, since both your devices are below 16,  but keep in mind that lspci gives its output in hexidecimal and the xorg.conf wants their info in decimal.

I know that the current rage is to have as little in your xorg.conf as you can get by with, but when there are multiple video cards that *are not the same*, you need to specify them.
Same with multiple monitors, if they are different, then you need to specify them so they are detected correctly.  Auto-configurating, like ati and nvidia do, is great when it works, but it doesn't always work.  Then you have to specify.